# Take a path from bash options and setting up default value

Tags: bash

## bash

Hi! I have to make a bash script that takes a directory as an option.
If other options are given, the output should only be "Error".
Let's c  be the value given to the only argument if no argument is given,
then c =. (Point)!

But i don't know how i can make this.
Can you help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to provide an argument to a bash function which needs to be a directory.  If it is not a directory then the program should display "Error".  If no argument is supplied, the directory should be "." (current directory?)

```
#!/bin/bash    

if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then
    c=$1
    if [[ ! -d $c]]; then
        echo "Error"
    fi
else
        c="."
fi
```